# Can we tell Jenkins to execute half of my test in a one slave and other half in another slave machine

Tags: jenkins

Is there any way to set up a Jenkins job where it will execute part of the test cases in a `Node A` and other part of the tests in `Node B`.
Technically, I need to reduce my test executing time executing tests in parallel on two different servers (Agents).

In the worst case, I was planing to make two jobs which will run two different text.xml files and those XML files will contain different test classes.

Answer (score 1):

In a Jenkins pipeline you can run stages parallel:

```
    pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Run Tests') {
            parallel {
                stage('Test On agentA') {
                    agent {
                        label "agentA"
                    }
                    steps {
                        sh "run-testsA.sh"
                    }
                    post {
                        always {
                            junit "**/TEST-*.xml"
                        }
                    }
                }
                stage('Test On agentB') {
                    agent {
                        label "agentB"
                    }
                    steps {
                        sh "run-testsB.sh"
                    }
                    post {
                        always {
                            junit "**/TEST-*.xml"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2017/09/25/declarative-1/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So how does it going to decide which TC are going to run on agent 01 and  which TC are going to run on agent 02?

Comment: You have to decide that for him. Most testautomationframeworks/-tools have a way to run a subset of your tests. For example by using tags.

Comment: Will you available for a quick screen sharing session with me ,Coz I have so many questions to ask on thus Jenkins PIPELINE which is totaly new to me.

Comment: Finally I divide my XML file in to 2 files and add two different jobs